# Laravel update session lifetime before creating a session

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

in login window and Auth managment i cant set lifetime correctly. how to set that before creating a session such as:

```
Config::set('session.lifetime', '60');
```

second parameter is random and user can change that in login window

Answer (score 2):

You definitely should not change server's `session` lifetime in `Laravel` instance for each individual user. Instead, store session expiration time for individual user somewhere in database, next to the user data with the `timestamp` of last user activity. Whenever difference between last user activity and new request will be more then expiration time (that you saved in database), do `Session::flush()`